# How to generate war file in Gradle project

Tags: gradle, war, build.gradle

I have creating a sample gradle project. My project build generates a jar file.I am using the `gradle clean build` command. How do I generate a war file for my project instead of a jar file?

Answer (score 17):

You need to include the [war plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html) to the Gradle build.

```
apply plugin: 'war'
```